# Nexus 7 folder is empty on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, nexus-7

I connected my Nexus 7 with my laptop (running Windows 8) via USB. Its being detected as "Nexus 7" however it says "This folder is empty" on Explorer. Am I doing something wrong?

If it's of any use, touch is not working on Nexus 7 and I am trying to back up all my files before I try a factory reset to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: You need to unlock your Nexus 7 before the files are visible to Windows. At least, I have to do so.

Comment: As what type is the Nexus 7 connected? Go to Settings => Memory => again Settings => USB-mode.

Comment: I cannot find Memory in the Settings... You mean Nexus 7 settings right? Right now I'm accessing the tablet using a mouse via OTG cable

Comment: When this happens with my Nexus 7, I just unplug the USB cable and then plug it in again, and the files appear.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton It worked I unlocked the screen using the OTG cable and the files were recognised! Thank you for your suggestions regardless guys.

Comment: same with nexus 5.. just had to unlock the screen. tnx!